# Take member functions as parameters from multiple classes

Tags: c++, oop, pointer-to-member

I am working on an input system. In this system, objects can register a function to be called when a certain key is pressed. However the methods that are registered are members to that object, so my register function has to look something like this:

void register(EventType type, Class* object, void (Class::*function)()){
    //save this
}

The issue is that it won't always be the same class registering a function, so this won't work. Is there anyway round this?

Comment: Templates.  Create a base Callback class with templated subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store `std::function<void()>` in the class where you register the callbacks, and then add a function template `register` member function:

```
struct Foo
{
  template <typename F>
  void register(EventType type, F&& fun)
  {
    // make an std::function<void()> from fun and store
  }
};
```

Then, you do the binding of `Class` instance and `Class` member function on the caller's side.

```
struct Bar { void bar() {} };
void foobar() { std::cout << "foobar!\n"; }

Foo f;
Bar b;
f.register(event1, std::bind(&Bar::bar, b)); // will call b.bar()
f.register(event2, foobar);                  // will call foobar()
```

Comment: What would a call to this function look like? I take it F&& is a function pointer.

Comment: @handuel `F&&` is a template technique that uses reference collapsing to work fine with lvalue or rvalue references. You don't have to worry too much about that. I added a small example. I also wrote about something similar on [a blog](http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/simple-observer-pattern-implementation-c11/).

Comment: @handuel note that this requires C++11, but if you don't have compiler support, then you can do pretty much the same with `boost` (except for the `&&` thing).

Comment: Are you aware if this will work with g++? Will I have to use command line args to tell it which standard to use when I invoke the compiler?

Comment: @handuel it depends on the version. I am not sure what version you need for all the features to work, but I have a feeling 4.6 should be enough.

Comment: @handuel: Current versions of GCC default to C++03, so you'll need to specify `-std=c++11` (or `c++0x` on older versions) to use the modern standard.

Comment: Actually, one final question, how is this done if the function takes parameters. Do I just make std::function<void(paramType)> from it, or something else. (All the function will always take the same type, (a pointer to the input event information)).

Comment: @handuel Yes, exactly. `std::function<void(paramType)>` means a function object that returns `void` and takes a `paramType` parameter.

Comment: Right, I rigged together some test code just taking int as a param, and it's throwing tons of errors. Do you know what I'm doing wrong: template <typename T>
void passFunc(T&& funcPoint){
    function<void(int)> func  = funcPoint;
    func(2);
}

Comment: @handuel how are you calling that function?

Comment: passFunc(bind(&Test::function, test));

Comment: @handuel OK, when you have parameters in a member function, you need to play some more tricks. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/7c1ZKf). What is missing is `std::placeholders::_1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I am unsure as to how that works (I'm sure google can be my aid), all my problems are solved. You have been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it without templates and function pointer. You have a observer (callback) class like this:

```
class MyCallback {
    public:
    virtual void run(int abc)
    {
        cout << "MyCallback::run(" << abc << ")" << endl;
    }
};
```

Then you instantiate your observer class with a parent class MyCallback:

```
class Test : public MyCallback
{
    public:
    void run(int abc)
    {
        MyCallback::run(abc);
    }
};
```

The class that calls all observers:

```
class Subject
{

    vector<MyCallback*> observers;

    public:

    void reg_observer(MyCallback* cb)
    {
        observers.push_back(cb);
    }

    void call_out(int abc)
    {
        vector<MyCallback*>::iterator it;
        for(it=observers.begin();it!=observers.end();it++)
        {
            (*it)->run(abc);
        }

    }

};
```

A test code:

```
void testcb()
{
    Test ttt;
    Subject s;

    s.reg_observer(&ttt);
    s.call_out(123);
}
```